enable last login for ftp server
Trying to use pam_lastlog to log last login on a ftp server, vsftp with virtual users. The virtual users are not present as "real" user on the system but use the pam_pwdfile module as authentication. Followed mostly the guide from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon
man vsftpd.conf:

session_support
This controls whether vsftpd attempts to maintain sessions for logins. If vsftpd is maintaining sessions, it will try and update utmp and wtmp. It will also open a pam_session if using PAM to authenticate, and only close this upon logout. You may wish to disable this if you do not need session logging, and you wish to give vsftpd more opportunity to run with less processes and / or less privilege. NOTE - utmp and wtmp support is only provided with PAM enabled builds.
Default: NO

With the session_support enabled, auth.log shows:
Dec  2 11:09:15 ftp2 vsftpd: pam_umask(vsftpd:session): account for monitoring not found
Dec  2 11:09:15 ftp2 vsftpd: pam_unix(vsftpd:session): session opened for user monitoring(uid=getpwnam error) by (uid=0)

NB: username is monitoring
vsftp seems to be updating wtmp correctly and works:
# last -s today -3 -w
monitoring vsftpd:31604 127.0.0.1        Mon Dec  2 12:53 - 12:53  (00:00)
monitoring vsftpd:31597 127.0.0.1        Mon Dec  2 12:48 - 12:48  (00:00)
monitoring vsftpd:31589 127.0.0.1        Mon Dec  2 12:43 - 12:43  (00:00)

When I add "session required pam_lastlog.so", I cannot login anymore to the ftp server (getting a "530 Login incorrect."), auth.log does log any information while pam_lastlog is enabled.
Configuration
/etc/pam.d/vsftpd:
session sufficient pam_lastlog.so
auth    required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/vsftp-users
account required pam_permit.so

/etc/vsftpd.conf:
allow_anon_ssl=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
hide_ids=YES
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
local_root=/mnt/ftp/home/$USER
local_umask=022
log_ftp_protocol=YES
mdtm_write=YES
nopriv_user=vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
pasv_address=ftp.domain.com
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=50100
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_promiscuous=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/domain.pem
session_support=YES
ssl_ciphers=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:@STRENGTH
ssl_enable=YES
strict_ssl_read_eof=NO
debug_ssl=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/conf.d
user_sub_token=$USER
utf8_filesystem=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO

Ubuntu 22.04
vsftpd 3.0.5 (from os repo)
It seems pam_lastlog has been deprecated in favor of pam_lastlog2, this require "util-linux" package >2.40 which is not available yet on any current ubuntu LTS. So for now we're stuck with pam_lastlog.

Could not get it to work so I made a quick python script to call from pam:
session optional pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/pam_lastsqlite.py --file /path/to/sqlite.db

The script will only keep the last login:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sqlite3
import argparse
import time
import os
import socket

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--create', action='store_true',
                    help='Create database file and initialize')
parser.add_argument('--file', dest='file', type=str,
                    help='Location of the database file')
parser.add_argument('--cleanup', dest='cleanup', type=int,
                    help='Cleanup old entries older than x days')
args = parser.parse_args()


def create_db(db):
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE lastlog(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, user TEXT,ruser TEXT, host TEXT, rhost TEXT, date INTEGER)")
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
        print("Database initialized")
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"create_db: {e}")


def update_db(db):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        current_time = int(time.time())
        params = (
            os.environ.get('PAM_USER'),
            os.environ.get('PAM_RUSER'),
            socket.getfqdn(),
            os.environ.get('PAM_RHOST'),
            current_time,
        )
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM lastlog WHERE user=? AND ruser=? AND host=? AND rhost=?", params[:-1])
        existing_user = cursor.fetchone()
        if existing_user:
            cursor.execute(
                "UPDATE lastlog SET date=?  WHERE user=? AND ruser=? AND host=? AND rhost=?", (current_time,) + params[:-1])
        else:
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO lastlog (user, ruser, host, rhost, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", params)
        conn.commit()
        # print(f"User '{params[0]}' {'updated' if existing_user else 'inserted'} successfully.")
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"update_db: {e}")


def cleanup_db(db, days):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        current_time = int(time.time())
        old = current_time - (days * 86400)
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM lastlog WHERE date < ?", (old,))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"cleanup_db: {e}")


# MAIN
if args.create:
    create_db(args.file)
    exit(0)
elif args.cleanup:
    cleanup_db(args.file, args.cleanup)
    exit(0)
else:
    update_db(args.file)
    exit(0)

You can then list login:
sqlite3 /path/to/sqlite.db 'select * from lastlog'

You can list accounts that have not login in a while:
export oldftp=$(date --date="1 year ago"  "+%s")
sqlite3 /path/to/sqlite.db "SELECT * FROM lastlog WHERE date < $oldftp"

If anyone finds a better solution I am all ears.
